# Reprojecting layer to coordinate system with arbitrary 0,0 point in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, cad

Is there a way (ideally in QGIS as this is what I am most comfortable working with but open to other solutions) to reproject a layer so that X,Y information are changed according to an arbitrary point that is defined as 0,0 coordinates?

My goal is to use a topography layer in Civil3D, but Civil3D crashes when dealing with very high X and Y values. What worked was to divide and limit the number of decimals, but I would like to be able to choose a point that will be the 0,0 for a new custom projection.

Answer (score 2):

Move your objects within current coordinate system with `native.translategeometry` algorithm or python code (`QGeometry.translate(dx, dy)` method).

OR

Create new coordinate system based on current. Copy proj4 description of current CS and change x_0 and y_0 parameters. Something like this:

```
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=9 +k=1 +x_0=100000 +y_0=-200000 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m
```

and reproject your layer with `native.reprojectlayer` algorithm